# Iframe does not seem to update the src unless I walk through the code in debugger

Tags: javascript

```
function goToPage(strFilePath)
{
    //change iframe source to be the new one
    try 
    {
     $("#frameContent").attr("src",strFilePath);     
    } catch (error) {
        var x = error;
    }

}
```

the variable strFilePath would be something like: "location/page4.html"

When I run this code NORMALLY all it does is refresh the iframe with the same exact page, over and over- despite a different "strFilePath.html" being provided each time.

When I DEBUG this code in chrome, and step through it line by line using F9 or whichever key it is, it magically loads the correct page as expected.....

What gives??

This is how goToPage gets called ->

```
function nextButton()
{
    //return the html path from the array that has the next corrosponding screenID, but if it is the last element in the array
    //then we move them to the exam.
    iCurrentScreenID = iCurrentScreenID + 1;
    goToPage(arrLessonPages[iCurrentScreenID]);
}
```

Comment: How is `goToPage` called?

Comment: @epascarello User clicks an html button either "Next" or "Previous" and when they click either button it gets the location of the HTML page that is either the next page, or the previous page. The variable passed to goToPage is something like "location/page3.html" or "location/page4.html"

Comment: So you do not cancel the button click?

Comment: @epascarello What do you mean cancel the button click?

Comment: @epascarello I added some more code to the question, the "nextButton()" function is simply called by an HTML button

Comment: So cancel the click action, see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @epascarello okay give me a few minutes, I will write back.

Comment: @epascarello yes, that did it. Thank you.